# Cómo deshabilitar y habilitar el campo al hacer clic en el radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy desarrollando un e-commerce desde el que el usuario tendrá que elegir un medio de pago:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Me gustaría que el usuario haga clic en el módulo "Dinheiro", el campo "Troco" para estar habilitado, y al hacer clic en otros campos, el campo "Cambiar" se deshabilita nuevamente.

Lo intenté de esta manera, pero no pude.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">                        
<div class="deals-row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-qrcode fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" id="outros" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Pix"  checked  />
                                Pix
                                </label>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
        <i class="fa fa-money fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="dinheiro" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Dinheiro" onclick="desabilitar(this.checked)" />
            Dinheiro    
        </label>                        
    </a>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Troco:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control valorMonetario" id="troco" disabled>
            </div>          
</div>  
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio"  id="outros" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Cartão de Crédito"  />
                                Cartão Crédito
                                </label>
                        </a>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Cartão de Débito"  />
                                Cartão Débito
                                </label>
                        </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Mumbuca"  />
                                Mumbuca
                                </label>
                        </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="PAT"  />
                                PAT
                                </label>
                        </a>
</div>      
</div>          

<div class="text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" name="Submit" value="Finalizar">Finalizar Pedido <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>      
</div>                      
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function desabilitar(){
        if(document.getElementById('dinheiro').checked){
           document.getElementById('troco').removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        if(document.getElementById('outros').checked){
           document.getElementById('troco').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que solo estás asignando evento a un radio, pero debe ser a todos y con el evento `change` porque `click` solo selecciona.

Revisa los comentarios en el código y pregunta si tienes dudas.

```js
// Obtener todas las formas de pago por nombre de campo
let pagamentos = document.querySelectorAll('[name="FormaPagamento"]');
// Obtener elementos que se van a analizar o modificar
let dinheiro = document.querySelector('#dinheiro');
let troco = document.querySelector('#troco');

// Recorrer formas de pago para asignar evento
pagamentos.forEach(pagamento => pagamento.addEventListener('change', desabilitar));

function desabilitar() {
    // Habilitar solo si se seleccionó dinheiro
    if(dinheiro.checked) {
        troco.disabled = false;
    } else {
        troco.disabled = true;
    }
    // Se puede hacer con una sola línea
    // troco.disabled = !dinheiro.checked;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
        <i class="fa fa-money fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="dinheiro" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Dinheiro">
            Dinheiro    
        </label>                        
    </a>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Troco:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control valorMonetario" id="troco" disabled>
            </div>          
</div>  
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 focus-grid"> 
    <a href="#!" class="pagamento"> 
                            <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio"  id="outros" class="w3-radio" name="FormaPagamento" value="Cartão de Crédito">
                                Cartão Crédito
                                </label>
                        </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby.